# Extending Button to make a reusable custom button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to extend the Button class to make a reusable button, which I've called NavBarButton.

Very simple : the button is an Image with a TextBlock below that image.

Here is the NavBarButton class :

```
public class NavBarButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(NavBarButton),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Image",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(NavBarButton),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Here is the NavBarButton markup :

```
<Button Name="NavBarButton" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Image Source="{Binding ElementName=NavBarButton, Path=Image}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=NavBarButton, Path=Text}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

And here is how I place the NavBarButton inside a user control :

```
<local:NavBarButton x:Name="UserNavBarButton" 
    Width="80" 
    Height="80" 
    Image="/Resources/User.png" Text="Test"/>
```

The problem is : I can't see neither the text ("Test" in this case) or the image.

Note : The image has build set to Resource. If I put "/Resources/User.png" directly on an image, I can see it without any problem.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Do i understand you right that you want to bind some other control outside the control template from within the control template? That is horribly broken design... Anyway, why do you use a <Button> in your XAML at all to show the image and text? Shouldn't the NavBarButton be used to to show the image and text. Lo and behold, you have also used a <local:NavBarButton> in your XAML -- what is the <Button> for? Should you not have a control template for the NavBarButton (which i guess should look like the control template you used for the button)? I am confused about what you try to achieve

Comment: I thought that using <Button> in the XAML was the way to extend the Button control, and ControlTemplate was used to design how the control will be rendered.

Comment: Okay, somewhere/somehow you are confused on a fundamental level about control templates. You have a NavBarButton, and that NavBarButton should show the image+text, correct? Apply a control template to the NavBarButton which specifies how it renders the image and text. You can use the template control you made for the button and apply it to the NavBarButton instead. Replace your bindings with "{TemplateBinding *PropertyName*}" to make them bind to the properties of the template owner (the NavBarButton).

Comment: If you got this and understand the basics about control templates, the next step could be to relocate the (default) control template for your NavBarButton into some resource dictionary, so that you do not have to specify that control template again and again whenever you are using a NavBarButton. But for now, to help you understand how control templates work i would suggest to keep it simple and to apply the control template where you use the NavBarButton(s) in the XAML...

Comment: Hi Joan, Sandesh shows the correct way below.  The trick always when using binding is to set the data context.  If you look at what Sandesh did below, there's this sneaky little statement "DefaultKeyStyleProperty" which in essence sets up the datacontext.  Don't feel bad as WPF binding can drive a person crazy!

Comment: @JohnPeters, do not mix up DataContext with defining style keys for a control. These two things are completely unrelated to each other...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified your code to fix it.

The mark up for your `NavBarButton` which is defined in `Generic.xaml`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NavBarButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ResourceKey={x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:NavBarButton}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Image}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The most important part of the `CustomControl` is that you need to override the style in a static constructor which is missing in your code.

```
public class NavBarButton : Button
{
    //Unless you override the style it will never be rendered
    static NavBarButton()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(NavBarButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(NavBarButton)));
    }



    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Text",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(NavBarButton),
    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Image",
        typeof(ImageSource),
        typeof(NavBarButton),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(null));


    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now you should be easily able to use it

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <custom:NavBarButton Text="Test" />
</Window>
```

Comment: But is it normal that even though my NavBarButton inherit from Button, My style completely overwrites the default button style (the mouse hover color, etc.) ?

Comment: @JoanLeaven, yes. Button has a (default) control template which uses some element that is responsible for the "button chrome" (including the color change when hovering over the button). The control template for your NavBarButton uses a different control template which does not specify this "button chrome" element. What makes matters complicated is that this "button chrome" element will be a different element depending on which theme is being used by the app (which usually is again depending on the OS on which the app runs). (contd...)

Comment: For each supported theme, WPF has different resource dictionaries with button control templates using different "button chrome" elements. If you want to you use those "button chrome" elements for your NavBarButton, you would need to maintain different resource dictionaries and need your application load the appropriate resource dictionary depending on the active theme. Another simpler approach could be to not replace the control template but rather specify a *DataTemplate* for arrangement of the image+text and assign it to the *ContentTemplate* property of your NavBarButton. (contd.)

Comment: Now, within a DataTemplate you can't use the "{TemplateBinding ...}" bindings, because the parent of this template is not the NavBarButton itself, but rather a ContentPresenter control used by the default Button ControlTemplate internally... You would then need to use bindings which "look" for the NavBarButton control (so it can bind against its Image and Text properties), using the **FindAncestor** mode for a binding, like this: `"{Binding Path=Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:NavBarButton}}}"`

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanations @elgonzo. I will change my Template to a DataTemplate and bind using FindAncestor.

Comment: @JoanLeaven : For your second comment you can see that the style is inheriting the default style of `Button` using `BasedOn` attribute. A lot of these styles are coming from the theme engine of the OS. So you have 2 options on hand. One overwrite the default style yourself so that  you get more control on the look and feel (which you did) or leave it to the OS. @elgonzo has done a good job explaining it to you.Thanks :)