# Is it possible to make a user control in C#(WPf) that can inherit from a Button just like how Custom Controlls do?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to make some customized controls that can be add to the Toolbox. I tried making User controls, but the problem is that when I define the Content property for any of the controls, they just simply disappear. I looked online and I solved this problem by making Custom controls. But I want to make user controls that can inherit( or extend) the standards from existing controls such as Button.

Can this be done? User Control inheriting from Other Controls?

Comment: These are two questions. The first: why do user controls disappear from the toolbox and 2: can you inherit a user control from a button. Please reduce the question down to what you want be be solved.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025479/extending-button-to-make-a-reusable-custom-button This would help you! you should edit the control template of the control and override them. And you should create Dependency properties and bind them properly.